# Can there be a company shareholder which is not a company owner?

Tags: definition, shareholders

I would define a *shareholder* as someone who is eligible for a certain percentile amount of profit from a company, from dividends and/or from selling the company; this person may or may not be an owner of the company as described in a local (state-operated) company registrar.

I think and I might be wrong that in Israeli law *any* shareholder would have some amount of "ownership" on a company.

Comment: For clarity, are you asking, A: whether they are entitled by law to be registered as an owner, B: whether they can claim part of any dividend or sale, or C: whether they necessarily have voting rights?

Comment: @Davislor I meant just owner, but, international-law-wise I would would expect "owner" to cover all three options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Shareholders own the company

There may be different classes of shares in a company with different rights (voting, dividends, preferential distribution etc.) but if you own a share you own (part of) the company.

Just as a side note, there are companies that are not limited by shares - their ownership structure is different. Similarly, there are unit trusts where ownership of a share entitles you to distributions, making you a beneficiary but the owner is someone else (usually a holding company).

Comment: There are also profit sharing plans that can amount to a person being "eligible for a certain percentile amount of profit from a company". Some better deals even focus on *revenue* sharing. While those aren't shares, might be contracts worth looking into for OP